How to handle POST requests in Next.JS and display the data in a different page?
I'm trying to do the following:

have a form (which is client rendered) in a page, let's say /foo, that is doing a POST request to /bar
let the user fill that form
when the user submit the form, I'd like to display the /bar with the data submitted from the form above.

The only way I kind of succeded was to create a server action that stores the data into a cookie then do a redirect to the actual page.
Which I find it pretty much awful in terms of... everything.
//edit:
What I'd really like is to submit the form without any JS involved, so basically the form is:
<form method='POST' action='/bar'>
</form>

This part works, but I can't find any way to get the data while I'm on /bar page.
//edit2:
I realize that this may be achieved by using the req param:
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {}

But unfortunately the app router doesn't allow that.
//edit3:
I guess what I really need is to have a server action that points to a different page.
(I'm using latest Next with app router and next-intl)

Are after submit are you redirecting to /bar page using revalidatePath("/bar") ?

@cantdocpp i'm trying to submit a form the old fashion way. Without any JS involved, just good old <form action='/bar'>

I don't think next js form was supposed to be used in old-fashioned way like that. The closest thing you're getting is server actions. For example: <form action={bar}>

Yeah, that's how I do it now, but I find it very cumbersome because I literally need the form data from one page to a completely different page.

If you have database, you don't even need the concept of transfering data from one page to another. You can just store the form data into the database and get the data in another page. To be honest, full-page form submit is not a use-case for next.js or any frontend framework

@cantdocpp what's the best way in nextjs (or any frontend framework) to have two pages with completely different layouts and pass the data from one page to another?
(no db involved atm)

As long as you have root layout (which is recommended, btw), you can use react context. Other way is to use localStorage. Depending on your form data, you can also use searchParams. If i were you, i'd just store the data inside some JSON files on the server

@cantdocpp searchParams is useless, as I could just use action=GET on the form. I do not have a root layout as it's a completely 99.9999% different page (basically only the fonts and SOME css is common across the pages)

First of all, two separate page with two separate layout without any root layout can produce some bugs, possibly related to route and redirecting in next js. It's based on my experiance and this is a known issue in next.js. Secondly, i'd recommend you still save the form submit data on the server, you can save it inside a JSON or CSV file to be honest

Your use cases is easily solveable by using pure server-rendered framework like laravel. I do believe that next.js is not for every site.
